# Would AJAX, PHP and MySQL make a good socket for a online poker game?

Tags: mysql, ajax, multiplayer

I haven't yet determined what the UI would use (flash, HTML, etc.) but I'm curious if you guys think mysql could make for an acceptable socket for a multiplayer poker game?  The reason I'm considering using a DB is because that is the only way I know how to accomplish this and I know nothing about XML sockets or anything like that.  Would performance be an issue for dialup and slower mobile connections?  Could I potentially run into problems with trying to sync user turns and flops?  Should I just bite the bullet and go with a different type of socket? If so, what would you suggest and where would be a good place to start educating myself? Thanks.

Comment: I don't really know what you reffer to as "Socket", but MySQL is now owned by Oracle, and it's very stable and capable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an inline poker game the technology you will use will certainly be the **less important problem**. The main problem will be in the way you get all subsystems connected between each others and how you ensure security at all levels (from the humans ensuring physical health of you server to the OS envirronment of your players, with maybe some jurists and gunmens -- and that makes a LoooOOot of levels :-) )

But if you want technical considerations I would personnaly use Zend Framework as a PHP library/framework and PostgreSQL as the database. And a really big part of the application would rather be coded in the database, via pl-pgsql things, than in PHP. PHP would be there to provide some ui in different levels (humans, web services, etc), and some of the security levels checks. Ajax interactions  would be made with jQuery. No doubt I would prefer PostgreSQl to MySQL for an application with a lot of data, fine security levels, a lot of replications, and a lot of data checks and automatic updates.

Answer (score 0):

PHP / MySQL isn't as fast as some systems (e.g. as ASP.NET) but in slow connections like dialup/mobile that won't be a problem.

The advantage of PHP from my standpoint (which isn't what everyone needs) is that it is very transparent, i.e. you easily control the HTTP transmission and the response. That may be an advantage for you.